Understanding the flash translation layer - SSD emulation
Can anyone suggest me a blog/article on how to get an NVMe simulation environment up and running? I'm basically looking at using NVMe as an emulated device in Qemu and tracing the read, write and stat syscalls to see what's going on.
However, I would also like to see what's happening at the Flash translation layer. On searching a bit, I ran into a plethora of information which left me a bit dazed (as is usual with information overload these days). There's this whole OpenChannelSSD thing (which is apparently a part of lightNVMe or some such)
I tried following some examples from github but most of them seem broken or incomplete. If any of you have successfully crafted such a setup or know a link which does this end to end, I'd be obliged to know!
thanks!
